# Understanding "ne résister pas à l’envie de savoir"

Tags: sens, expressions

The question is on the highlighted clause in this passage from Flaubert's L'Éducation Sentimentale.

> Frédéric éprouvait un certain respect pour lui, et **ne résista pas à l’envie de savoir son nom.** L’inconnu répondit tout d’une haleine :
>      
>   « Jacques Arnoux propriétaire de l’Art industriel, boulevard Montmartre. »

**Question**

Should I attribute the diction (wording) to Frédéric?

**Background**

In other words, am I supposed to imagine the character saying, "Why sir, I cannot resist the urge to know your name?"

I think it may turn on whether *ne résister pas à l’envie de savoir* is something of a set phrase.

I am a beginning student in French (and don't have any good sense for these things), but the wording sounds too high flown for the novel's narrator, who has thus far been quite plain spoken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En effet, Frédéric a posé une question mais on ne peut qu'en imaginer la teneur car

> [il] ne résista pas à l’envie de savoir son nom.

sont les mots de Flaubert, ce n'est pas du discours indirect. Il peut lui avoir dit « Quel est votre nom ? », « À qui ai-je l'honneur ? » etc...

Par ailleurs :

> Je ne résiste pas à l'envie de savoir votre nom.

est d'un registre un peu plus élevé que :

> Je ne peux pas m'empêcher de vous demander votre nom.

qui serait la formulation normale d'un jeune provincial du XXI<sup>e</sup> ça ne peut pas être qualifié de *high flown* et je dirais que « ne pas résister à » est plus proche de *I can't help...* que de *I can't resist the urge...*

---

Indeed Frédéric uttered something to ask Jacques Arnoux his name. But we can only presume what he would have said because *Frédéric éprouvait un certain respect pour lui, et ne résista pas à l’envie de savoir son nom.* is not indirect speech and are **Flaubert's own words**.

Besides :

> Je ne résiste pas à l'envie de savoir votre nom.

or in what would be 21st century casual wording for a young man:

> Je ne peux pas m'empêcher de vous demander votre nom.

Although *Je ne résiste pas à l'envie de...* is of a higher register than *Je ne peux pas m'empêcher de...* it is not as formal as the English "I cannot resist the urge to...".  It's probably closer to "I can't help..." as far as register is concerned.

---

Answer reworded to remove ambiguousness. Thanks to qoba.

Comment: Thank you for both the French and the English versions! So, we don't have formal indirect speech, or formal speech attribution (to character). But is there no sense (hint, suggestion) that the narration is probably mimicking the character's diction? If Frédéric simply said, "What's your name," and the narrator chose to use the roundabout way of telling us that, wouldn't that make him a strange narrator?

Comment: @Catomic I personally do not feel it is a mimicking of the narrator's speech, and  *Je ne résiste pas à l'envie de savoir votre nom* does not sound to me out of character for a 19th century educated 18 year old (don't forget he's just got his baccalauréat which in the 19th century placed him among the educated part of the population). As I said an 18 year old in the 21st century would probably, but not necessarily, say it differently. By the way I do not want to sound as if I were a Flaubert specialist, I've read most of his novels as part of any literary education in the 20th century.

Comment: N'auriez-vous pas mélangé "discours indirect" avec "discours direct" ?

Comment: @AnneAunyme : pas du tout. Je veux bien dire que ce n'est pas du discours indirect qui rapporterait les paroles de Frédéric mais bien les mots de Flaubert.

Comment: Flaubert peut, en utilisant ses propres mots, faire du discours indirect. Ici cela y ressemble mais je ne saurais l'affirmer avec certitude car il y manque certains éléments typiques de celui-ci.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that Frederic used these words as much as anything else. For all we know, he just asked "comment vous appelez-vous ?" or "vous êtes ?". The point of Flaubert not saying what he said exactly is that the thought process (driven by curiosity) is more interesting to us than the words he used to ask for someone's name.

Comment: @qoba I don't understand what in my answer makes you think that Frederic "used these words". " we can only **presume** what he **would have** said" does *not* mean he **actually** said it.

Comment: What made it unclear to me was that you gave two examples of what Frederic might have said, and both of them include the explicit expression of a desire that he's unable to contain. That makes it sound like you're saying it was at least something along those lines. I suggest adding a few more examples of ways we can imagine Frederic to have asked for the man's name — eg "comment vous appelez-vous ?" or "à qui ai-je le plaisir...?"

Comment: @qoba    I see. My bad, So what I said wasn't clear.  In your quotes I was  answering OP's query about *ne résister pas à l’envie de savoir* and telling him  it didn't sound  "high flown" to a French person, which is to me an important part of his question.  For the rest I thought that *On ne peut qu'en imaginer la teneur* *ce sont les mots de Flaubert* or "we can only presume" was clear enough to show it does not reflect Frédéric's words but his feelings as described  by Flaubert.

Comment: Ah - I missed it because the observation that the sentence is high-flown is not phrased in the OP as a question. Suggest then to add sections to your answer and restate the second question you're answering.

Answer (score 2):

No, Frédéric did not say “Why sir, I cannot resist the urge to know your name?”, any more than he said “I have some measure of respect for you”. The sentence describes Frédéric's thought processes, there is no indication that it reflects what he said. It is likely that he simply asked the man what his name is.